# Returning a string Backwards in C

Tags: c, string, function, return

In this piece of code i wanted to scan a word and return it backwards. I tried using different methods, but i dont seem to make it work.

This is what I am now left with.

```
#define WORD_LENGTH 256

char * stringBackwards(char *a) {

     char *palindrom = malloc(WORD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
     int k = 0;
     for ( int i = WORD_LENGTH; i >= 0; i--, k++) {
          palindrom[k] = a[i];
     }

     return palindrom;
}

main() {
     char word[WORD_LENGTH];

     printf("Please enter a word \n");
     scanf_s("%s", word, WORD_LENGTH);

     printf("%s", stringBackwards(word));

     return 0;
}
```

It always returns me some strange symbols in my console.

I hope some of you can help me in correcting this.

Comment: you're swapping the whole buffer, not only the string. so you get the garbage which is in the end of `word` at the start of your reversed string.

Comment: I already though of that. But even if I set the WORD_LENGTH to 4 and enter 4 random letters I get garbage.

Comment: First of all you need to remember that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** character strings*. That null-terminator need to be handled. Then think of the case where the user inputs e.g. a two-character string? What will the rest of the 253 characters be initialized to? Hint: They *won't*.

Comment: yeah, because string isn't nul terminated: 2 issues

Comment: Perhaps you need to learn about the [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function? Or get [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which will explain all this. And think about that when you use your function in the call to `printf`, who will call `free` for the memory you `malloc`?

Comment: Well this would obviously help alot. I am starting to learn C... dont be to rude please. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

you're swapping the whole buffer, not only the string. so you get the garbage which is in the end of `word` at the start of your reversed string. The next mistake here is *not* terminating your string.

I would fix it like this (and rewrite your loop with increasing indexes, or it's very easy to make a 1-off mistake):

```
char * stringBackwards(const char *a) {

 int sz = strlen(a);
 char *palindrom = malloc(sz+1);  // size + 1 for nul-termination char
 int k;
 for ( k = 0; k < sz; k++) {
      palindrom[k] = a[sz-k-1];
 }
 palindrom[k] = '\0'; // don't forget to nul-terminate
 return palindrom;
```

}

aside: store the returned value to be able to free it if needed. Passing it to `printf` directly is a memory leak.

Comment: `k` is local to the for loop so you wont be able to access it after the loop.

Comment: thanks for this. And in "classic" C it's not even valid. fixed

Comment: Thank you for fixing it. I didnt know about the nul-terminate thing. And also thank you for showing me the strlen function.